# Unable to configure my router

Tags: wireless-networking, security, router

I have an Eminent EM4050 wLINK which is connected to a SpeedTouch ST5x6v6. The Eminent is transmitting Wi-Fi, but it's not protected. I want to configure the router so I can set up a password for the Wi-Fi, but I'm unable to configure it. `http(s)://192.168.1.1` doesn't work. I can, however, configure the SpeedTouch by typing its gateway (`10.0.0.138`) into my browser.

Is there a way I can change my router's settings, or do I have to buy another router/modem?

Comment: In order to connect to the device you have to use the devices actual ip address `192.168.1.1` isn't the address of the device.  Determine what the address of the Eminent EM4050 by looking at the DHCP configuration on the SpeedTouch.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.1.1 is not working because the router has a default IP of 10.0.0.138, regardless of whether you are trying to HHTPS to it or not.

Within the router bios, in your basic network settings, you should be able to change the default IP address of the device AS WELL as the scope of the addresses that the DHCP will assign....that being if you want all 192 local addressing. (unless you would prefer to keep the 10 addressing)

WLAN settings will contain your Wi-FI security settings you are trying to configure....WPA...WPA2, whatever you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you are connected to the WIFI from the CMD line enter `ipconfig`.  The gateway is your IP for configuring the Eminent device.  If this does not work, unplug your Eminent router from your network and plug into your PC directly.  Repeat the `ipconfig` cmd.  Make the changes to the WIFI protection with it plugged directly into your PC.  Unplug it from your PC and put it back in the original configuration.

This is based on the assumption you are having the Eminent device as the router and the Speedtouch is merely sending the connection to it.